# The prohibition of "Bekhukoteyem" (in their likeness) and the Jewish architecture

Tags: halacha, architecture-design

> "*Rabbi Yehuda says: One who did not see the great synagogue [deyofloston] of Alexandria of Egypt never saw the glory of Israel: They said that its structure was like a large basilica, with a colonnade within a colonnade.* [Sukkah.51b](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Sukkah.51b.6?vhe=William_Davidson_Edition_-_Vocalized_Aramaic&lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en)

Clearly, R"Y describes a basilica-like, Greek-style synagogue in Egypt, and indeed many European synagogues traditionally resemble Greek/Christian architectural styles:
[image: Dohány Street Synagogue, Budapest].

I would speculate, that if every Jew is commanded on having an attire distinctive from surrounding gentiles, following the prohibition of Bekhukoteyem", all the more, Jewish religious institutions, as Rambam ruled [Avoda Zara 11](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Mishneh_Torah%2C_Foreign_Worship_and_Customs_of_the_Nations.11.1?vhe=Torat_Emet_363&lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en):

> "*It is forbidden to follow the customs of the idolaters, or to imitate them neither in dress nor in hair-trimming and like customs, for it is said: "And ye shall not walk in the customs of the nation which I cast out before you" (Lev. 20.23),*

I also noticed that in Arabic countries, synagogues look very Arabic-like.

What about Jewish architecture?